# Using file descriptors to communicate between processes

Tags: python, ipc, zsh, file-descriptor

I have the following python code:

```
import pty
import subprocess
os=subprocess.os
from subprocess import PIPE
import time
import resource

pipe=subprocess.Popen(["cat"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, \
                      close_fds=True)
skip=[f.fileno() for f in (pipe.stdin, pipe.stdout, pipe.stderr)]
pid, child_fd = pty.fork()
if(pid==0):
    max_fd=resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE)[0]
    fd=3
    while fd<max_fd:
        if(fd not in skip):
            try:
                os.close(fd)
            except OSError:
                pass
            fd+=1
        enviroment=os.environ.copy()
        enviroment.update({"FD": str(pipe.stdin.fileno())})
        os.execvpe("zsh", ["-i", "-s"], enviroment)
else:
    os.write(child_fd, "echo a >&$FD\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    print pipe.stdout.read(2)
```

How can I rewrite it so that it will not use `Popen` and `cat`? I need a way to pass data from a shell function running in the interactive shell that will not mix with data created by other functions (so I cannot use stdout or stderr).

Comment: Why can't you just `subprocess.Popen()` the shell directly?

Comment: @llasram because I need an interactive shell to capture arguments passed to completion builtin `compadd`. No tty - no interaction - no completion.

Comment: I'm not quite following... Could you provide a concrete example?

Comment: @llasram What example? If I have an interactive shell, I can use tab to get completion. When I press tab zsh invokes some shell functions that are able to find suggestions. These functions use `compadd` builtin to pass found suggestions to zsh completion system. But there are some problems: 1. zsh refuses to be interactive when it is not connected to a tty. 2. completion functions may echo something to stderr and zsh itself echoes to stdout. In this code to capture `compadd` arguments I can define `compadd` function, make it pipe them to given FD and then use `os.write(child_fd, "echo /\t")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I've got a handle on your question now, and see two different approaches you could take.

If you absolutely want to provide the shell in the child process with an already-open file descriptor, then you can replace the `Popen()` of `cat` with a call to `os.pipe()`.  That will give you a connected pair of real file descriptors (not Python `file` objects).  Anything written to the second file descriptor can be read from the first, replacing your jury-rigged `cat`-pipe.  (Although "cat-pipe" is fun to say...).  A socket pair (`socket.socketpair()`) can also be used to achieve the same end if you need a bidirectional pair.

Alternatively, you could simplify your life even further by using a named pipe (aka FIFO).  If you aren't familiar with the facility, a named pipe is a uni-directional pipe located in the filesystem namespace.   The `os.mkfifo()` function will create the pipe on the filesystem.  You can then open the pipe for reading in your primary process and open it for writing / direct output to it from your shell child process.  This should simplify your code and open the option of using an existing library like [Pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect) to interact with the shell.

Comment: Thanks, I was not using `mkfifo` because it creates new files. And I tried to use `os.pipe()`, but failed to guess that I should use second fd in child script and first in parent. The idea of using `pty.fork` came after examining source codes of pexpect.